# Is it good to minify and format JavaScript for SO questions?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Personally, I feel as if I would be able to read JS snippets more efficiently and objectively without distracting variable names, via minified scripts.

**Would you rather deal with minified or non-minified JS in questions?**

Non-Minified:

```
function sendGame(req, res, sales, settings, categories, players) {

    var game = new Object();

    game.sales = sales;

    game.players = players;

    game.settings = settings;

    game.categories = categories;

    JSONgame = JSON.stringify(game);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://website.com',
            'Content-Length': JSONgame.length,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    res.write(JSONgame);
    res.end();

    //console.log('Game: ' + JSON.stringify(game, null, 4));

    console.log('--------------------------------------');

    console.log('User ' + req.body.username + ' successfully retrieved game!');

    console.log("Game: " + JSON.stringify(game, undefined, 2));
}
```

Minified (and formatted):

```
function sendGame(e, t, n, r, i, s) {
    var o = new Object;
    o.sales = n;
    o.players = s;
    o.settings = r;
    o.categories = i;
    JSONgame = JSON.stringify(o);
    t.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://website.com",
        "Content-Length" : JSONgame.length,
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    });
    t.write(JSONgame);
    t.end();
    console.log("--------------------------------------");
    console.log("User " + e.body.username + " successfully retrieved game!");
    console.log("Game: " + JSON.stringify(o, undefined, 2))
}
```

Comment: Surely single letter variable names aren't more readable than meaningful names?

Comment: @duplode You're right, it was just a thought. I think I just like being able to fit more code into the question with less width. I hate when the code in my questions overflow sideways.

Comment: @jt0dd: Usually you can wrap the lines intelligently—on commas, say—and line it up nicely. In some cases, shorter names may be justified, but usually you'd shorten it to, say, a single word or an abbreviation thereof, rather than to a single letter.

Answer (score 6):

No; code should be left in its original, uncompressed form, although perhaps with excessive newlines (as in the first block) removed.

Besides plain readability (to me; I understand it's subjective), in the case of a so-called [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), keeping the original variable names might help someone decipher what is *really* being asked, so comments or maybe answers could answer their *real* question.